# How to save different classes extended from an abstract class

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have an application with many DisplayFields (rendered on a canvas) e.g. text, boolean, date etc. These DisplayFields have many variables in common such as color, shadow parameters, fill etc.

Because of these common values, I have defined BasicField as an abstract class.

From this abstract class I extend DisplayFieldText, DisplayFieldBoolean etc. Each of these is a separate class with additional variables specific to the field's function.

Now I need to save all DisplayFields to disk. So each field needs to save its core (Abstract Class variables) as well as its own parameters.

How do I go about this without lots of duplication of code?

Comment: The title is not a place for keywords/tags. The title should label your question in a way which other developers could get an idea of the problem before they actually check out the question. You title is very ambiguous, and I suggest editing it to attract users that understand the exact problem. I also suggest using more specific tags, such as `design` to ensure you question appears to people looking at questions with those specific tags

Comment: Title has been changed

Comment: As for the design aspect, [is `DisplayFieldText` a `BasicField`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a)? To me, it sounds like it's a behavior, and should be the responsibility of another object. Sounds to me as if you shoulf have some kind of `DisplayField` class (with the behavior of displaying), which accepts `BasicField` types. It seems like your current design violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), and you should redesign with that in mind.

Comment: Sorry if I confused people here by adding too much detail. The question is: there is an abstract class. From this class many other classes extend.
The abstract class has variables common to all extended classes. The extended classes have their own private variables. ALL variables need to be saved for each extended class i.e. the abstract class variables as well as the extended class variables.
Hope that clarifies things a little.

Comment: I (think) understood the problem. You could have the abstract class implement `Serializable`, then save objects (that are subtypes of the class that implements `Serializable`) to your drive via `ObjectOutputStream`. I was informing you that your design violates design principles, which are there to enforce scalable design (as well as make code easier to manage), hence why I commented and didn't give an answer. I wasn't trying to answer the question, rather than guide you towards a better design.

Comment: Thank you Vince, but I didn't think that my way of going about things (abstract class + extending classes) was a design violation since there is only one abstract class and all other classes extend from it. But I stand to be corrected - I'm still feeling my way around various design principles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caveat: I'm not sure how you're going about saving your data to disk, so this might not apply.

I'm going to assume that you're currently saving to disk using some structure that looks something like this:

```
class DisplayField {
    private int data;

    public void saveData() {
        // save data here
    }
}
```

This is a perfectly acceptable way to save your data, but when you introduce the parent class it would get kind of messy:

```
abstract class BasicField {
    public String sharedData1;
    public double sharedData2;
}

class DisplayField extends BasicField {
    private int data;

    public void saveData() {
        // save parent's data every time in every subclass!! Not fun!
        // save DisplayField's private data
    }
}
```

A good way to solve this problem is to use polymorphism. Since all the subclasses of BasicField are going to need to save their data, you can define the saveData() method in BasicField, and call it in the subclasses. This has a lot of other side-benefits, for example if you have a BasicField object, you know that it will be able to save its data. Also if you add more data to the BasicField later, you will only have to change a couple lines of code in BasicField instead of modifying all of its subclasses.

```
abstract class BasicField {
    public String sharedData1;
    public double sharedData2;

    public void saveData() {
        // save sharedData1
        // save sharedData2
    }
}

class DisplayField extends BasicField {
    private int data;

    public void saveData() {
        super.saveData();
        // save DisplayField's private data
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a great answer. It was the super.saveData() bit that I was missing and now it makes a lot of sense. Many thanks!